# Storing emails on phone

Tags: 8.0, apps, email

Hi is there an option to store and manage your emails in phone. Or not even store, just being able to check all of your emails stored on email account. Or, if not, is there some good email app which is worth using?

Comment: Just like all smartphones, windows phones are also having mailbox configuration settings. Can you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To view the entire archive of your mail, you can set the sync settings of an email account to "download email from" "anytime".